# Solving this trig limit without L'hopital: $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital, pi

I know similar questions have been asked but I could not find any answer that applies to my case, so I'll ask anyway. I'm having trouble getting rid of an indeterminate without using derivatives

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}$$

One idea I had was to multiply both sides of the fractions by $$\pi x$$  like this
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin(\pi x)\pi x}{\pi x^2-\pi x}$$ to cancel out the sine but then I realized that I could not do that because x tends to 1, and not to 0. What can I do?

Comment: Let $x=y+1$ first

Comment: Can you use calculus? Your limit is the same as $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin \pi x - \sin \pi}{x-1}$$ which should hopefully look familiar.

Comment: You can do it by simple calculations: Evaluate the expression on the left of $1$ ($0.999$), and on the right of $1$ ($1.001$).

Comment: @TobyMak that method can only give you an approximate answer.

Comment: I marked the answer of @TheDeadLegend as answer, but all of the answers helped me understand the point,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(\pi(1-h))}{1-1-h}$$
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(\pi h)\pi}{-\pi h}\tag{Multiply and divide by pi}$$
$$-\pi$$

Comment: thanks, this really helped me understand the exercise. just for clarification $$sin(x) = sin(\pi - x)$$ right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly @twkmz

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1-x}
&=&\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(\pi (1-h))}{h} \\
&=&\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(-\pi h)}{h} \\
&=&\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{-\sin(\pi h)\pi}{\pi h} \tag{common limit} \\
&=&-\pi.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $\pi x=t+\pi$, so $x-1=\frac{t}{\pi}$; for $x=1$ we have $t=0$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(t+\pi)}{t/\pi}=
\lim_{t\to0}-\pi\frac{\sin t}{t}
$$

---

On the other hand the limit is the derivative at $1$ of the function $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$, and
$$
f'(x)=\pi\cos(\pi x)
$$
so
$$
f'(1)=-\pi
$$

(Note: this is *not* l’Hôpital.)

Answer (score 0):

With *equivalents*:

Set $x=1+h$. We know $\sin u\sim_0u$, so 
$$\frac{\sin\pi x}{x-1}=\frac{\sin(\pi+\pi h)}{h}=-\frac{\sin\pi h}h\sim_0-\frac{\pi h}h=-\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sin \pi x = \sin (\pi(x-1) + \pi) = - \sin (\pi(x-1))
$$
SO
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin \pi x}{x-1}= -\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\sin \pi(x-1)}{x-1} = -\pi
$$